# Dropbox datastore addObserver not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

This is the code for detect the dropbox changes. But it is not call while change the data from other device.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[self.datastore_ addObserver:self block:^()
 {
    if (weakSelf.datastore_.status.incoming)
    {
         //NSDictionary *changes = [weakSelf.curDataSrore_ sync:nil];

    }
}];

[datastore_ close];
```

Let me know any mistake in my code?

Comment: I believe this was discussed in a Dropbox API support forum. From that thread, it looked like the issue was that the datastore was being immediately closed after setting up the observer.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203450235-Datastore-observer-not-working ]